# Python script to determine XYZ of tip of cone

Tags: python, scripting

My scene contains a cone named 'MyCone'

I'm trying to construct a Python script: get_XYZ_for_tip( 'MyCone' )

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: This Q is a bit vague - do you know which vertex is the tip of the cone? - or would the script have to analyze the mesh and detect this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script finds the vertex that is referenced by more edges than other vertices, this should meet the 'tip-criteria' to make a function `getTip` simply return the `vert.co` value.

```
import bpy


obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
mesh = obj.data


v_edge_tot = [0] * len(mesh.vertices)
maxedges = 0
maxvert = None
for edge in mesh.edges:
    for vert in edge.vertices:
        v_edge_tot[vert] += 1
        count = v_edge_tot[vert]
        if count > maxedges:
            maxedges = count
            maxvert = vert

vert = mesh.vertices[maxvert]
print(maxvert)
print('v %f %f %f' % (vert.co[:]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using BMesh this can be a one liner :), assuming your in editmode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

tip_index = max((len(v.link_edges), i) for i, v in enumerate(bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data).verts))[1]
```

The same idea expanded (longhand):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

vert_user_index = []
for i, v in enumerate(bm.verts):
    vert_user_index.append((len(v.link_edges), i))
tip_index = max(vert_user_index)[1]
```

*Note that its building a list, where the one liner version uses a generator (which is more efficient)*