# Open blend file like txt file

Tags: python, scripting

Easy question with probably no easy answer: How can I open a blend file just like e.g. a txt or a python file?

I'm not simply interested in the objects of the scene (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447680/blender-open-and-parse-a-blend-file-from-python-script)), but the full -let's say- architecture of the script. I had a look at [blender-aid](https://code.google.com/archive/p/blender-aid/source/default/source) and the [DNA Exporter](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/doc/blender_file_format/BlendFileDnaExporter_25.py), but I couldn't figure out how to use it or rather don't think they are what I'm looking for.

Please be patient, I'm completely new to Blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender has a fairly complex system of storing its data using (RNA and DNA). It also stores a vast set of different types of data (colors, textures, assets, images, fonts, objects, modifiers, settings,...). I'd like to think of a blend file as a zip archive with a nested set of directories and files underneath it. But it isn't actually a zip.

What kind of data are you exactly looking for? Lets assume that you are looking for the shape of the objects inside of a blend file. then you could make a python scripts that goes through all objects of `bpy.data.objects as ob` for instance. You could then find the geometry the object is composed by using `ob.data` which usually will result in an entry from `bpy.data.meshes`.

You can than use this to dump its vertices: [How to iterate through all vertices of an object that contains multiple meshes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6139/how-to-iterate-through-all-vertices-of-an-object-that-contains-multiple-meshes)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the blend structure! I'm probably most interested in the object and its details (position, shape, texture) as well as the camera and lightning infos.